LWC HelpText RTL issue
I have a LWC with a Helptext inside, my LWC is built to be displayed in RTL.
When user switch langague to a RTL one, all the LWC is switch to RTL mode expect of the helpText, that open in LTR mode (same bug as in the standard record page layout).
From what I see here , the issue is with the 'slds-nubbin_bottom-left' that should be 'slds-nubbin_bottom-right'.
is there any way to fix it ?
thanks,

